# How to force styles in CiviMail templates?

Tags: civimail, templates

When a basic user uses a template to write an email, is there any way to force the styles in the message? For example, the most common case is when the user creates links in the message body and these are set to default blue color links.
OK, when the template includes CSS styles in the message body these are applied correctly, but then, when you send it, there are some mail clients that do not display these styles and because they require inline CSS styles.

Any ideas or tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force inline CSS with [this extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/css-inline).